# Unable to get required values from json string using Newtonsoft Json.net

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I'm trying to iterate through all "DicomModalities" in the following json string and get data in the following format but my code isnt working and gives the error "'name' is not a member of 'JObject'"

required format >>> (dicommodality name)-AET eg for the first entry it would be "Modality1-PACS1" and for the second it would be "Modality2-GINKGO"

```
Json:

{
"DicomModalities" : {
      "Modality1" : {"AET" : "PACS1",
      "Port" : 4242,
      "Host" : "192.168.253.5",
      "AllowEcho" : true,
      "AllowFind" : false,
      "AllowMove" : true,
      "AllowStore" : true},
      
      "Modality2" : {"AET" : "GINKGO",
      "Port" : 11112,
      "Host" : "127.0.0.1",
      "AllowEcho" : false,
      "AllowFind" : false,
      "AllowMove" : false,
      "AllowStore" : true}
      }
}
```

---

```
My Code

Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

Sub Main()
    Dim jsonString As String = "{ "DicomModalities" : { "Modality1" : {"AET" : "PACS1", "Port" : 4242, "Host" : "192.168.253.5", "AllowEcho" : true, "AllowFind" : false, "AllowMove" : true, "AllowStore" : true}, "Modality2" : {"AET" : "GINKGO", "Port" : 11112, "Host" : "127.0.0.1", "AllowEcho" : false, "AllowFind" : false, "AllowMove" : false, "AllowStore" : true} } }"

    Dim json As JObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString)
    Dim dicomModalities As JObject = json("DicomModalities")
    Dim message As String = ""

    For Each modality As JProperty In dicomModalities.Properties()
        message = modality.Name & "-" & modality.Value("AET").ToString() 
        MessageBox.Show(message)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: "my code isnt working" what it means pls? do you have an error message?

Comment: sorry about  that...I have updated the post

Comment: @What do you realy want to get. Your code is very confusing. Do you want just the first properties values or you want all properties?

Comment: Is that JSON correct?

Comment: @Serge Ideally want to get each DicomModalities's following info Modality Name(eg Modality1, Modality2), AET(eg PACS1,GINKGO) and Host(eg 192.168.253.5, 127.0.0.1) in the format (Modality Name)(AET)(Host )and add it to a dropdown list. so for example the first iten in the dropdown would be "(Modality1)(PACS1)(192.168.253.5)"

Comment: @CetinBasoz yes its correct

Comment: Your code runs, and prints `Modality1-PACS1` and `Modality2-GINKGO`, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/bH00Mx.  The only problem is that the definition of your string literal `jsonString` does not compile because the embedded double quotes are not escaped as `""`.  What is your problem?  Please [edit] your question to indicate what you need to do.

Comment: @dbc in dotnetfiddle it works perfectly but in Visual Studio 2022 no luck. Please see screenshot >>> https://imgur.com/6wBgONL

Comment: @ranasrule I am using VS 2022 and Newtonsoft v13. Evertything is working properly. What versions are you using?

Comment: @Serge same as you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is working in my VS 2022, but you can try this syntax

```
       Dim list As New List(Of String)

        For Each modality As JProperty In dicomModalities.Properties()
           list.Add( modality.Name & "-" & modality.Value.SelectToken("AET").Value(Of String) & "-" & modality.Value.SelectToken("Host").Value(Of String) )
        Next

        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(vbCrLf, list))
```

output

```
Modality1-PACS1-192.168.253.5
Modality2-GINKGO-127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that JSON is a good one, anyway:

```
Private Sub Main()
    Dim myData = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(s, New With {
        .DicomModalities = New With {
            .Modality1 = New With {
                .AET = "",
                .Port = 0,
                .Host = "",
                .AllowEcho = False,
                .AllowFind = False,
                .AllowMove = False,
                .AllowStore = False
            },
            .Modality2 = New With {
                .AET = "",
                .Port = 0,
                .Host = "",
                .AllowEcho = False,
                .AllowFind = False,
                .AllowMove = False,
                .AllowStore = False
            }
        }
    })
    Console.WriteLine($"Name1: Modality1, Value1: {myData.DicomModalities.Modality1.AET}")
    Console.WriteLine($"Name2: Modality2, Value2: {myData.DicomModalities.Modality2.AET}")
End Sub

Shared ReadOnly s As String = "{
""DicomModalities"" : {
      ""Modality1"" : {""AET"" : ""PACS1"",
      ""Port"" : 4242,
      ""Host"" : ""192.168.253.5"",
      ""AllowEcho"" : true,
      ""AllowFind"" : false,
      ""AllowMove"" : true,
      ""AllowStore"" : true},
      
      ""Modality2"" : {""AET"" : ""GINKGO"",
      ""Port"" : 11112,
      ""Host"" : ""127.0.0.1"",
      ""AllowEcho"" : false,
      ""AllowFind"" : false,
      ""AllowMove"" : false,
      ""AllowStore"" : true}
      }
}"
```

Better, maybe you would want to create classes and deserialize with that class:

```
Sub Main
    Dim myData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Root)(s)
    Console.WriteLine($"Name1: Modality1, Value1: {myData.DicomModalities.Modality1.Aet}")
    Console.WriteLine($"Name2: Modality2, Value2: {myData.DicomModalities.Modality2.Aet}")
End Sub

Shared ReadOnly s As String = "{
""DicomModalities"" : {
      ""Modality1"" : {""AET"" : ""PACS1"",
      ""Port"" : 4242,
      ""Host"" : ""192.168.253.5"",
      ""AllowEcho"" : true,
      ""AllowFind"" : false,
      ""AllowMove"" : true,
      ""AllowStore"" : true},
      
      ""Modality2"" : {""AET"" : ""GINKGO"",
      ""Port"" : 11112,
      ""Host"" : ""127.0.0.1"",
      ""AllowEcho"" : false,
      ""AllowFind"" : false,
      ""AllowMove"" : false,
      ""AllowStore"" : true}
      }
}"

Public Partial Class Root
    <JsonProperty("DicomModalities")>
    Public Property DicomModalities As DicomModalities
End Class

Public Partial Class DicomModalities
    <JsonProperty("Modality1")>
    Public Property Modality1 As Modality
    <JsonProperty("Modality2")>
    Public Property Modality2 As Modality
End Class

Public Partial Class Modality
    <JsonProperty("AET")>
    Public Property Aet As String
    <JsonProperty("Port")>
    Public Property Port As Long
    <JsonProperty("Host")>
    Public Property Host As String
    <JsonProperty("AllowEcho")>
    Public Property AllowEcho As Boolean
    <JsonProperty("AllowFind")>
    Public Property AllowFind As Boolean
    <JsonProperty("AllowMove")>
    Public Property AllowMove As Boolean
    <JsonProperty("AllowStore")>
    Public Property AllowStore As Boolean
End Class
```

EDIT: Knowing it would always be this depth and structure, but not knowing names like "modularity1", "modularity2" you could deserialize into nested Dictionaries (better would be to make that an array if you had control on JSON generated):

```
Sub Main()
    Dim myData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, Object))))(s)
    Dim modalities = myData("DicomModalities")

    For Each modality In modalities
        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {modality.Key}, Value: {modality.Value("AET")}")
    Next
End Sub
```

[Dotnet Fiddle demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7Lg8uq)

Comment: thanks for the  answer but there could be 100 modalities so in the below code you provided I would have to define a JsonProperty for each one. Any way around that?

Partial Public Class DicomModalities
        <JsonProperty("Modality1")>
        Public Property Modality1 As Modality
        <JsonProperty("Modality2")>
        Public Property Modality2 As Modality
End Class

Comment: @ranasrule, if you have control over the JSON then simply correct it JSON level, making those modalities an array. Otherwise you could also do it unconditionally using a Dictionary approach. Editing my answer for a sample.